# Error in creating indexes in Solr 8.1.1 running on an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, solr, sitecore, serverless, azure-appservice

We have created a new Sitecore environment with the Azure market place solution "Azure Experience Cloud" Sitecore version 9.3 XM scaled topology with Solr search.

Steps we followed for creating Solr App service:

1. Created a blank sitecore 9.3 solution from Azure market place and created a Web app for Solr.
2. Unzipped the Solr 8.1.1 package and copied all the contents to `wwwroot` folder of the Web app created for Solr.
3. Created a new Solr core by creating a new `{index folder}` folder and copied `conf` from the `/site/wwwroot/server/solr/configsets/_default`.
4. Created a `core.properties` file with `numShards=2` & `name={index folder}`.

We get the below error:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
> Index dir 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr{index
> folder}\data\index/' of core '{index folder}' is already locked. The
> most likely cause is another Solr server (or another solr core in this
> server) also configured to use this directory; other possible causes
> may be specific to lockType: native

How can we resolve the above problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with Solr running on an Azure App Service and usually gets resolved by restarting the App Service. Of course, it is not a proper solution, but can work short-term.

Moving forward I would recommend to create a virtual machine in Azure and setup Solr there or, alternatively, look at a [SearchStax](https://www.searchstax.com/) solution offering a fully managed Solr-as-a-Service.

Also please take a look at a [relevant post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23466/solr-cores-locking-v-9-0-2) on Sitecore Stack Exchange.